# JqueryUI Tabs - need change URL onSelect Tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hyperlink, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have menu TABS STRUCTURE:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#tabs-1'>TabGroup1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tabs-2'>TabGroup2</a></li>            
  </ul>
  <div id='tabs-1'>
    <a href='tab1_link1.html'>TabGroup1-link1</a>
    <a href='tab1_link2.html'>TabGroup1-link2</a>
  </div>
  <div id='tabs-2'>
    <a href='tab2_link1.html'>TabGroup2-link1</a>
    <a href='tab2_link2.html'>TabGroup2-link2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TASK**: 
I need autochange location to the first link in selected tab.
So, when I click on second tab, the page will reload and will show opened second tab with selected first link (tab2_link1.html).

I have found [solution](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tabs-when-clicking-on-tab-load-a-new-page-instead-of-hide-show-divs), which makes tab an active link, but this works if tab is empty div, and I need to activate link from tab's content, so this isn't solving my task.

Comment: To clarify, you want the CONTENT of the first link displayed on the tab? or simply to activate/select that tab that contains that link?

Comment: I want to activate first link in tab, which must reload page, not tab content. Tab contenet in my situation is just menu string with links to other site parts and pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "tabsselect" event triggers when a tab is selected.  So let's bind to that:

```
$( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
    //Here we have:
    ui.options // options used to intialize this widget
    ui.tab // anchor element of the selected (clicked) tab
    ui.panel // element, that contains the contents of the selected (clicked) tab
    ui.index // zero-based index of the selected (clicked) tab
```

SO, in your case you need to set the window location to the first anchor element href url in the selected tab.

```
window.location.href = $(ui.panel).find('a:first').attr(href);});
```

So given the above, and YOUR markup, this will navigate to the first link location referenced on that tab.

```
$( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
    var myhref = $(ui.panel).find('a:first').attr('href');
    alert("Here we go to:"+href);
    window.location.href = href;
});
```

Final script:

```
$( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
     window.location.href = $(ui.panel).find('a:first').attr('href');
});
```

Sample working example of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/PyM7p/

Note to self:  It DOES seem odd here to have multiple links on a tab when only the first one will ever be used on the current page.  It is not my page markup though.

Comment: Thank for you solution, I will test it soon and write & vote it it helped! And about your note: Not only one will be used. All will be used, but when you select tab, first must be activated and loaded, not just show the list of links in group, as default behavour is. Then, you can select other links in this tab, manualy clicking them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! It works itself. I met problems with using it together with my other task code, but I desided to ask this question separately, because it's another type of problem!

Comment: Here is the question of conflict I met: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622495/selection-tab-and-onselect-code-conflict-infinite-reloading-of-page

Answer (score 0):

Add listener do select event and in this function set location.href and then browser reload.

Comment: @koral - you have simply restated his question as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

Tab select event is discarded in JQuery 1.9+ as described [here](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/). To work with jquery 1.9+ you have to do something like this

```
$( "#tabs" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {

} );
```

where UI have following four objects in it. All of them are Jquery objects. So no need to wrap them again.

- newTab

The tab that was just activated.

- oldTab

The tab that was just deactivated.

- newPanel

The panel that was just activated.

- oldPanel

The panel that was just deactivated.

So final code will look like this

```
$( "#tabs" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {
     window.location.href = ui.newTab.find('a.ui-tabs-anchor').attr('href');
} );
```