# Selection tab and onselect code conflict - infinite reloading of page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, conflict, onselect

I use JQueryUI TABS plugin.

There is my tabs structure.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#tabs-1'>TabGroup1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tabs-2'>TabGroup2</a></li>            
  </ul>
  <div id='tabs-1'>
    <a href='tab1_link1.html'>TabGroup1-link1</a>
    <a href='tab1_link2.html'>TabGroup1-link2</a>
  </div>
  <div id='tabs-2'>
    <a href='tab2_link1.html'>TabGroup2-link1</a>
    <a href='tab2_link2.html'>TabGroup2-link2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use such code to select and load first link in tab, when tab is selected.
It works itself.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

        // Activate first link on tab
    $( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
     window.location.href = $(ui.panel).find('a:first').attr('href');
   });  
});
```

**BUT in my task addition code for selecting tab by URL parameters strongly nessesary.
So if visitor opened link from second tab-group, second tab must be showed opened, not default first one.***

I have working code which show correct tab when link from this tab is loaded (no AJAX or such, just ussual links). `$URL['part']` is variable I recieve from my URL in engine, this works fine separately.

```
<?php if(@$URL['part']=='part2'){
    echo '<script>$(function() { $("#tabs").tabs("select","#tabs-2"); });</script>';    
} ?>
```

***BUT when I use both these code-blocks it cause page repeatedly infinite reload :-(***

**UPDATED:**

Notice, that both of blocks of code use SELECT event, that why the looping occurs.

**UPDATED2:**

I suppose, if use ONCLICK for loading link when tab is selected, and SELECT on activation tab due to URL settings, it can solve the problem. But I don't know how to write this in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is complete final solution I found, which WORKS (crossbrowser)!**

Creates tabs

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Select the tab which must be active for the current URL we have

```
<?php 
if(@$URL['part']=='part1'){
    echo '$(function() { $("#tabs").tabs("select","#tabs-1"); });'; 
} 
if(@$URL['part']=='part2'){
    echo '$(function() { $("#tabs").tabs("select","#tabs-2"); });'; 
} 
?>
```

The below code MUST be after we started tabs and selected which one is now active, otherwise we will recieve infinite url-reloading!

```
$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
            window.location.href = $(ui.panel).find('a:first').attr('href');
        }
    });
});
```

***So, when I moved tab selection based on URL to the begining of code, this solved all the issues and make solution this simple!***

Answer (score 1):

Does this work if you move the processing inside the tabs creation:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        window.location.href = $(ui.panel).find('a:first').attr('href');
    }
});
```

In a study of you code, it might be better to check the URL and not go anywhere if it is the same page, either by link OR by tab select:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        checkUrl(event, ui.panel);
    }
});
// handle link click on current tab
$('div>a').click(function(event) {
    checkUrl(event, event.target);
});

function checkUrl(event, ui) {
    var ehref = $(event.target).attr('href');
    var wl = window.location.href;
    var currentLocation = typeof ehref == "undefined" ? wl: ehref;
    var newLocation = $(ui.panel).find('a:first').attr('href');
    if (currentLocation != newLocation) {
        window.location.href = newLocation;
    }
};
```

In reference to your comment, there is a create handler so you would have the bind inside that:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    create: function(event, ui) {
       $( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
           window.location.href = $(ui.panel).find('a:first').attr('href');
       });
    }
});
```

but I am unsure of the event firing on the creation sequence, and if the select of the tab occurs before or after the create event (I would think after) as I have not tested this.

Comment: or possiblly put the `.bind()` inside a `create:function(){}`

Comment: The code in your unswer cause same trouble as code in my question. The problem is that I use SELECT event in both code blocks, so it cause inifinite reloads... I see why the problem occures, but not the way to fix it :-(. And about code in your comment... I don't understand how to implement it, I am quite new to JQuery.

Comment: I added some ideas in my question, they can help to find solution

Comment: Thanks for detailed unswer! Trying to understand it and make work now. At the first attempt - no tabs shown at all, but no errors in console either.

Comment: Your solution looks too complex for me to make it work as I wish. But I found alternative idea, which I posted in my own unswer. But it works with errors, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

---

UPDATED:

**This solution isn't correct! I keep it for historical reasons and comments are below it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10642137/1368570 - this is working correct solution: clear and simple**

---

I have found solution very close to task:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function MySelect(event, ui){
    // selected - currently selected tab (string)
    var clicked_tab = '' + ui.index //clicked tab

    if(selected !== clicked_tab ){
        //So this code will works ONLY when another tab is selected, so no infinite loop        
        //alert(selected+'/'+ui.index);

            // Activate first link on tab
       $( "#tabs" ).bind( "tabsselect", function(event, ui) {
         window.location.href = $(ui.panel).find('a:first').attr('href');
       });
    }
}   

$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
            MySelect(event, ui);
        }
     });
});

        //retrieve the index of the currently selected tab
var tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
var selected = '' + tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); // from zero 0
</script>
```

Code to acrivate propper TAB basing on the URL parameter processed in my engine

```
<?php 
if(@$URL['part']=='part1'){
    echo '<script>$(function() { $("#tabs").tabs("select","#tabs-1"); });</script>';    
} 
if(@$URL['part']=='part2'){
    echo '<script>$(function() { $("#tabs").tabs("select","#tabs-2"); });</script>';    
} 
if(@$URL['part']=='part3'){
    echo '<script>$(function() { $("#tabs").tabs("select","#tabs-3"); });</script>';    
}
?>
```

**PROBLEM:**

When I go from 1-st tab to 2-d or 3-d, window.location.href don't work, URL dont changes.

If I go from any tab except frist, all works perfectly.

I am too tired today to find solution to this issue, if any one have ideas, will be glad to hear them!

Also, when I uncomment alert in my code, I see that selected var is [object Object]. So if I compare object with non-object, why this complete solution works well in most cases?

Comment: your "selected" variable will be a jQuery object, so the result you see is correct. You will need to get the `selected.index()` 0 based index inside the select event handler `select:function(){/*here*/ selected = $(this).index();}` to get which one is selected - see my answer, the first part where I do the window.location.href= stuff as well as where you call your MySelect() function

Comment: The important part here for your understanding is that jQuery returns jQuery objects, and you might need to use some other stuff to get the actual object or value needed, and doing that in the right place makes all the difference.

Comment: Now, with that understanding, your "clicked_tab" will be that index by definition and the ui.panel there will be the one needed. SO you likley do not need the "bind" part in your function.  See my checkurl function where I check to make sure the first URL in the anchor tags is not the same URL as the page you are on, thus preventing the infinate reloads of the page.

Comment: Mark Shultheiss, I solve the problem by simply moving tab selection based on URL on top of my code! http://stackoverflow.com/a/10642137/1368570 - this is working solution. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I read it right, then you will be having same code in the HTMLs in the link, i.e.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#tabs-1'>TabGroup1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tabs-2'>TabGroup2</a></li>            
    </ul>
    <div id='tabs-1'>
        <a href='tab1_link1.html'>TabGroup1-link1</a>
        <a href='tab1_link2.html'>TabGroup1-link2</a>
    </div>
    <div id='tabs-2'>
        <a href='tab2_link1.html'>TabGroup2-link1</a>
        <a href='tab2_link2.html'>TabGroup2-link2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and you will be calling the `$( "#tabs" ).tabs()` on that page. IF so, why not use `$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 1 })` in the page where the link is supposed to redirect?